# Layout changes in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a contact form that I'm making for my WordPress website. When I test it on a standard webpage it looks like this:

[image: first picture]

But when I paste the code into WordPress it looks like this  and does a paragraph.

[image: second picture]

Any help on this?

I am also using elementor if that helps.

here is the code:

```css
.mailSec1 {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: #04aa6d 2px solid;
  padding-left: 37px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.mailSec1 input {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 215px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.mailSec1 button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 85px;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mailSec">
  <div class="mailSec1">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Tell us!">
    <button>Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It difficult to check the code it would be great if you provide the website URL.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to figure out what styles currently apply to the elements. Might be something like `display: block` on one of them, or an ancestor might be a `flexbox` element, or any number of things.

Comment: If you're pasting it in a wysiwyg editor it can sometimes add auto paragraphs too.
Using remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); typically disables this (adding it to functions.php or similar providing you're using a child theme).

More information on wpautop - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

As mentioned previously, it could be a number of things but should be fixable with a bit of CSS. We'd need more information regarding the issue to help any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Use `flexbox` to control the flow of elements in the `mailSec1` element.

```
.mailSec1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-right:  4px;
}
```

Comment: **down-voted for following reasons:** Missing explaination of the issue. Missing explaination of the "solution". Missing validation in form of a minimal, reproduciable code snippet. `flex-directcion: row;` and `flex-wrap: nowrap;` are superfluous as those are the standard values for those properties.

Comment: @tacoshy I used `flex-directcion: row;` and `flex-wrap: nowrap;` properties to make @jake explain the behaviour of flex items flow

Comment: this could have be done with a sufficient explaination that your answer is alcking in the first place. Please edit your answer to contain an explaination to be understandable for other users.

Comment: @tacoshy, this is purely a CSS conflict issue; no one can tell by just seeing the image how many CSS issues are there

Comment: @tacoshy I just provided the best solution for this type of issues

Comment: still could have contained way more explaination. You explain in your comments already mroe then within your answer...